# Django logging not happening in real-time

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, server, backend

I have a log configuration setting like the following:

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '[{levelname}] {asctime} {module}.{funcName}.{lineno} {process:d} {thread:d} {message}',
            'style': '{'
        }
    },
    'filters': {
        'filter_for_generic': {
            '()': 'service.logging.filters.FilterLevels',
            'filter_levels': [
                "INFO",
                "DEBUG"
            ]
        },
        'filter_for_mail': {
            '()': 'service.logging.filters.FilterLevels',
            'filter_levels': [
                "WARNING",
                "ERROR",
                "CRITICAL"
            ]
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file_generic': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs', 'generic.log'),
            'when': 'midnight',
            'backupCount': 30,
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'filters': ['filter_for_generic']
        },
        'file_diagnostic': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs', 'diagnostic.log'),
            'when': 'midnight',
            'backupCount': 30,
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'filters': ['filter_for_mail']
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'app': {
            'handlers': ['file_generic', 'file_diagnostic', 'mail_admins'],
            'level': 'DEBUG'
        },
        'jwt_validator_middleware': {
            'handlers': ['file_generic', 'file_diagnostic'],
            'level': 'DEBUG'
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file_generic', 'file_diagnostic', 'mail_admins'],
            'level': 'DEBUG'
        }
    },
}
```

Let's say I am something in my code as follows:

```py
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
LOGGER.info("Hello")
```

The `generic` log file gets created, but I can't see the `Hello` in the file. After hours (and most possibly the next day I get to see the `Hello` in the log file.

I tried to look for a bit and I came across something called `Buffered` output. Something like the logs are buffered before they're flushed into the file. If that's the case, how to flush it immediately to the file? Also, the file is supposed to be created at `midnight` but it doesn't get created just after midnight. When I executed `date` in the terminal of the deployment server it was already past `midnight` in UTC.

To summarize,

- How to make sure logs are flushed to the file immediately?
- How to make sure of the `timezone` that the django app is referring to for creating these log files?